# MVC Validation Attributes Kendo Grid don't work with UIHint

Tags: validation, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In my model I have

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "BIC Code is required")]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}$",ErrorMessage = "11 alphanumeric characters expected")]
    [UIHint("BicCode")]
    public string BicCode { get; set; }
```

The Template corresponding to the BicCode

```
@model string  
@(Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBox().Name("BicCode").Mask("AAAAAAAAAAA") )
```

During my kendo grid edition all my validation attribute are used except the ones from properties using UIHint.

How to deal with UIHint Validation and Kendo Grid?

Comment: Is your template in  Views -> Shared -> EditorTemplates ?

Comment: @SteveGreene Yes, and my template is ok, 
because when I press edit on a row of my grid, the MaskedTextBox is showed, it's just the validation is not managed on client side.

Comment: I think your issue may be how kendo renders the masked textbox. I assume the validation attributes are not there. You might try changing your template to MaskedTextBoxFor(m => m) as suggested [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/inline-editing-validation-with-drop-down-list-fails)

Comment: @SteveGreene Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Steve Greene in his comment.

Use `MaskedTextBoxFor(m => m)` instead of just `MaskedTextBox()` solved my problem.